# Derivative of $x^y-y^x=1$

Tags: calculus

There is a question in the past years papers of our examination. I can't find the derivative of

$$x^y-y^x=1$$

Is it possible to find its derivative? I would use $\ln$ if it was in multiplication.

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Answer (score 4):

Use implicit differentiation,
logs, and exponentials.

If
$1
= x^y-y^x
=e^{y\ln(x)}-e^{x\ln(y)}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=(e^{y\ln(x)}-e^{x\ln(y)})'\\
&=(y\ln(x))'e^{y\ln(x)}-(x\ln(y))'e^{x\ln(y)}\\
&=(y\frac1{x}+y'\ln(x))x^y-(x\frac{y'}{y}+\ln(y))y^x\\
&=\frac{y}{x}x^y+y'\ln(x)x^y-\frac{xy'}{y}y^x+\ln(y)y^x\\
&=\frac{y}{x}x^y+\ln(y)y^x+y'\ln(x)x^y-\frac{xy'}{y}y^x\\
&=\frac{y}{x}x^y+\ln(y)y^x+y'(\ln(x)x^y-\frac{x}{y}y^x)\\
\text{so}\\
y'
&= -\frac{\frac{y}{x}x^y+\ln(y)y^x}{\ln(x)x^y-\frac{x}{y}y^x}\\
\end{array}
$

You can get rid of either
$x^y$ or $y^x$
by using
$x^y-y^x = 1$.

If,
for example,
you use
$y^x = x^y-1
$,
you get

$\begin{array}\\
y'
&= -\frac{\frac{y}{x}x^y+\ln(y)y^x}{\ln(x)x^y-\frac{x}{y}y^x}\\
&= -\frac{\frac{y}{x}x^y+\ln(y)(x^y-1)}{\ln(x)x^y-\frac{x}{y}(x^y-1)}\\
&= -\frac{(\frac{y}{x}+\ln(y))x^y-\ln(y)}{(\ln(x)-\frac{x}{y})x^y+\frac{x}{y}}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^y$. Then $\log(f(x))=y\log(x)$. Then we take the derivative of both sides. $$\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}\log(x)+\frac{y}{x},$$ and $$\frac{df}{dx}=x^y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\log(x)+\frac{y}{x}\right).$$

Let $g(x)=y^x$. Then $\log(g(x))=x\log(y)$. We again take the derivative of both sides: $$\frac{1}{g(x)}\frac{dg}{dx}=\log(y)+\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx},$$ and $$\frac{dg}{dx}=y^x\left(\log(y)+\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}\right).$$

So if $f(x)+g(x)=1$, we can take the derivative to get $$\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{dg}{dx}=0.$$ Now just substitute.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the implicit function $$F=x^y-y^x-1=0$$ and compute its derivatives $$F'_x=y x^{y-1}-y^x \log (y)$$ $$F'_y=x^y \log (x)-x y^{x-1}$$ Now, by the implict function theorem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{y^x \log (y)-y x^{y-1}}{x^y \log (x)-x y^{x-1}}$$ and you can simplify partly as marty cohen suggested in his answer.